# Variable change in functional integral

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have following functional integral
$$ \int \mathcal{D}x\ f(x) \tag{1}$$
where $$\mathcal{D}x=\prod_t dx(t) \tag{2}$$
is the functional measure.

Now, I want to expand $x(t)$ as
$$x(t)=\sum_n c_n y_n(t) \tag{3}$$
where $c_n$ are coefficients, and $y_n(t)$ are orthogonal functions
$$\int dt y_m(t)y_n(t) = \delta_{mn} \tag{4}$$
It turns out that $y_n(t)$ can be integrated out in many physics applications, so I need to change the measure from $\int\mathcal{D}x$ to $\int d c_n$, so how to do this?

I have seen in some places that
$$\int \mathcal{D}x \rightarrow \prod_n N\int d c_n \tag{6}$$
How can we make it and how to identify the constant $N$? I think the renormalization constant $N$ should be related with the Jacobian determinant?

If you have any comments or answers, I would be appreciate it!

---

In a 2 by 2 example:
$$x(t)=c_1 y_1(t)+c_2 y_2 (t) $$
with $t\in[t_1,t_2]$.

The orthogonal relation becomes
$$ y_m(t_1)y_n(t_1)+y_m(t_2)y_n(t_2)=\delta_{mn}$$

so that
$$\int D x(t)=\int d x(t_1)dx(t_2)=|J|\int dc_1 dc_2 $$

where
$$ J=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial x(t_1)}{\partial c_1} & \frac{\partial x(t_1)}{\partial c_2} \\ \frac{\partial x(t_2)}{\partial c_1} & \frac{\partial x(t_2)}{\partial c_2}\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} y_1(t_1) & y_2(t_1) \\ y_1(t_2) & y_2(t_2)\end{pmatrix}$$

I can't see why $|J|=1$?

Comment: I have no experience with this, but this naively seems like if you’re choosing your $y_n$ to be an orthonormal basis, then the Jacobian determinant $dc_n/dx(t)$ would be like an infinite version of taking the determinant of an orthogonal matrix - i.e have value 1.

Comment: @Eric Could you please explain more on why the determinant of an orthogonal matrix equal to 1? Thanks! I want to show this in a discrete 2 by 2 example. I edit my post!

Comment: Orthogonal means $J J^T=I$, so $|J|^2=1$, so $|J|=\pm 1$. You can order your vectors so it’s positive 1.

Comment: I suspect that in general, the simpler basis might not be normalized like how you get factors of $2\pi$ when doing a Fourier transform.

Comment: @Eric Thanks for your comment! Very helpful!